# Error on installing Istio - Failed to apply manifests

Tags: istio

I am trying to follow this [doc](https://istio.io/pt-br/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-certmgr/). But when I try to execute this command:

```
istioctl manifest apply \
  --set values.gateways.istio-ingressgateway.sds.enabled=true \
  --set values.global.k8sIngress.enabled=true \
  --set values.global.k8sIngress.enableHttps=true \
  --set values.global.k8sIngress.gatewayName=ingressgateway
```

I receive the following error:

**Run the command with the --force flag if you want to ignore the validation error and proceed.**
**Error: failed to apply manifests: unknown field "k8sIngress" in v1alpha1.GlobalConfig**

My istioctl version is 1.6.0

Comment: Pixeto  I think the docs might not have been updated in the 1.6 release.In the 1.5.3 release I can see those options to be set.

Answer (score 1):

This can be worked around with [istio Operator](https://istio.io/docs/setup/install/standalone-operator/).

The values You have issues with would look something like this:

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
spec:
  components:
    ingressGateways:
    - name: istio-ingressgateway
      enabled=true
      enableHttps=true
      gatewayName=ingressgateway
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the doc you mentioned is not updated.In the english(main) branch of the website,the task is no more mentioned .[Check this link](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/).

May be [This](https://istio.io/docs/ops/integrations/certmanager/) helps.This doc gives guidelines on **integeration with cert-manager**.